# How to get a collection of georeferencing control points in an ArcMap document?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, .net, georeferencing

I have created control points (i.e. links) using ArcMap's Georeferencing toolbar.  How can I programmatically retrieve a list of these points? I'm looking for something like an enum of the links you would see in the Link Table (which is visible through the Georeferencing toolbar).

Preferably, I would then be able to step through these points and delete any one.

I am working with the ArcObjects SDK for C# .NET.

Comment: In the aux.xml file that is modified by ArcMap during georeferencing, GCPs are stored in SourceGCP and TargetGCP tags as an array of doubles.  I've used python to parse the xml file for these tags and their values.  I'm assuming the file can be rewritten to remove GCPs if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the API to do this is publicly available. From the [GeoreferenceUI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/#/GeoReferenceUI/00080000000s000000/) library documentation:

> The GeoReferenceUI library implements commands, tools, and dialog boxes that expose functionality used when rectifying spatial data. **This library is meant for internal use only. There is no public API exposed.**

Comment: That's too bad!  Looks to be the case though.  Thank you.  You can, however, access some of the controls on the Georeferencing Toolbar through their GUIDS.